# Is erlang's `binary_to_term` always able to read ANY of previous versions of binary `term_to_binary` produced?

Tags: erlang, elixir

The question is broad, here is my specific context:

- I only use `term_to_binary` to dump binary to postgresql, and read back with `binary_to_term`
- I don't use `term_to_binary` to produce any identifier or to compare data.
- My data types are only (from Elixir), map, list, string, number, nil, boolean. (i.e. no function, no atom, no struct)

Why not jsonb? It's ridiculously slow. Erlang term <-> binary is much much faster. (more than 10x)

Will `binary_to_term` be always able to read binary produced by any previous version of `term_to_binary`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One can enforce it with options, but no guarantee is provided and the format has changed during time *but* [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) always provided an option to read legacy formats for backward compatibility.

[More info in erlang docs](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-2).

Comment: Thanks, the `term_to_binary` doc above has option for float and atom. Float as textual guarantee is as safe as textual guarantee (I think it's safe, though textual representation _may be_, if possible, unreadable to future `binary_to_term`. I don't use atom so it's good.

However, `binary_to_term` option is `Opt = safe | used` that does not say thing about compatibility. 

I think it's quite safe for my use case, though I'm not sure.

Comment: I found a quote on https://elixirforum.com/t/cubdb-a-pure-elixir-embedded-key-value-database/23397/105 here:

`it means that the exact binary representation of terms could change between OTP releases, not that future releases might be unable to deserialize a binary created in older releases.`

No guarantee to be true but sounds pretty good to me.

Answer (score 2):

On the [Support, Compatibility, Deprecations, and Removal](https://erlang.org/doc/system_principles/misc.html) page, the external term format is not specifically mentioned. The distribution protocol is, though:

> **Erlang Distribution**
>
> Erlang nodes can communicate across at least two preceding and two subsequent releases.

And since the distribution protocol relies on the external term format, it's probably safe to assume that `binary_to_term` will be able to read data from at least two major releases back.

Comment: Thanks, I read the docs, the two releases compatibility still require data migration for all existing db records when bumping a major version since there's going to be data that's stored, untouched very long time.

I think it's easy enough for writing custom `2021_binary_to_2090_term` if any binary breaks. Hopefully we still use 0 and 1.